# How to use regular expression to match pattern repeatedly

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

public static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
string s1 = "#br/>This string has something at #br/> the end #br/>#br/>#br/>";      
        
string s2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s1,
                 "#br/>$", "");

        Console.WriteLine(s2);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

}

I want to remove occurrences of the string "#br/>" in three scenario:
1> From beginning :
output :"This string has something at #br/> the end #br/>#br/>#br/>"
2> From end :
output :"#br/>This string has something at #br/> the end"
3> From both end :
output :"This string has something at #br/> the end"

I want to archive this using regular expression. Could you please help.

Thanks,
Raju

Comment: `Regex.Replace(text, @"^#br/>|#br/>$", "")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wouldn't you want  `(?:#br/>)*$` to get all of the trailing matches?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Maybe. I was looking at the [question source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7a569393-c544-4b03-ad04-9374e2b6b9ae/view-source).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is your code** for all three cases.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputValue = @"#br/>This string has something at #br/> the end #br/>#br/>#br/>";

    string filterCase1 = @"^(?:#br/>)";
    string filterCase2 = @"^+|(?:#br/>)+$";
    string filterCase3 = @"^(?:#br/>)+|(?:#br/>)+$";

    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(inputValue, filterCase1, ""));
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(inputValue, filterCase2, ""));
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(inputValue, filterCase3, ""));

}
```

//**Output**

```
This string has something at #br/> the end #br/>#br/>#br/>
#br/>This string has something at #br/> the end
This string has something at #br/> the end
```

(referred from hint provided by @The fourth bird)

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are matching a single instance at the end of the string.

You can repeat 1+ times matching from either the start or at the end of the string.

```
^(?:#br/>)+|(?:#br/>)+$
```

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%23br%2f%3e%29%2b%7c%28%3f%3a%23br%2f%3e%29%2b%24&i=%23br%2f%3eThis+string+has+something+at+%23br%2f%3e+the+end+%23br%2f%3e%23br%2f%3e%23br%2f%3e&r=)

For example

```
string input = @"#br/>This string has something at #br/> the end #br/>#br/>#br/>";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"^(?:#br/>)+|(?:#br/>)+$", "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output

```
This string has something at #br/> the end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```cs
Regex.Replace(x, @"^(#br/>)+|(#br/>)+$", "", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
```

See [regex proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%23br%2F%3E%29%2B%7C%28%23br%2F%3E%29%2B%24&i=%23br%2F%3EThis%20string%20has%20something%20at%20%23br%2F%3E%20the%20end%20%23br%2F%3E%23br%2F%3E%23br%2F%3E&r=&o=n).

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #br/>                    '#br/>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2 (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #br/>                    '#br/>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

**[C# code](https://tio.run/##TU/BasMwDD3PXyGyHRLWZR8QVgalt5bBVtht4KaiMTi2seTisfXbMznt2AS2JL/np6eeHnofcZoSGXeEt09iHDv1v2t3mLl9xWOyOq5ziEhkvKNOqZD21vTQW00E66zHYFF9KZC4QsSaJZ28OcBWG1c3M3rhlDjpCBme4Lm63cfH5W4wJJ9iGT9oKf2IPJROM8wM4AEB3eHS/V1Vp26KmNhLlkkkxTJmMR6s7rHOC5nxUc/c5v77t7irFlDJmckvgctmrWwp5g2vdOAUsRHplbx7i@17NIwb47C@DhKw7HFW52n6AQ)**:

```cs
var x = @"#br/>This string has something at #br/> the end #br/>#br/>#br/>";
var results = Regex.Replace(x, @"^(#br/>)+|(#br/>)+$", "", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
Console.WriteLine(results);
```

**Results**: `This string has something at #br/> the end`